# Не работает строгое сравнение в массивах

Tags: php, foreach

Сделал тест, который по POST передает значения, также есть массив с правильными значениями, foreach обрабатывает это все. Но даже если в двух массивах одинаковые данные, оно считает как неправильное.

```html
$q[1]['true_answers'] = [2, 5];


if (is_array($_POST['q1'])) {
    $q1_request = $_POST['q1'];
    foreach ($q1_request as $answer) {
        echo $answer."\n";
    }
}

foreach ($q[1]['true_answers'] as $ans){
echo $ans."\n";
}

if($ans === $answer){
$goodq[] = "№1";
}
else {
$badq[] = "№1";
}
```

Comment: Непонятно почему вы сравниваете переменные за пределами форича,какой смысл тогда пробегать по массиву.Во вторых переменная ans и answer будет содержать только последнее значение из массива.

Comment: @quaresma89, массив для вывода значений, оно их выводит, а потом сравнивает и дает конечный результат + для того чтобы массивы перевести в обычные переменные с данными. Иначе пишет "Array"

Comment: Так как сейчас у вас написано, сравниваются только последние элементы в массивах.

Comment: @visman, а как проверят массивы полностью на строгое равенство?

Comment: На эту http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php функцию посмотрите.

Comment: @Visman так то `==`  вполне себе [сравнивает значения массивов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы поставиили жесткую проверку типов,у вас не будет положительных результатов сравнения.Все что приходит из `POST` и `GET` это все тип `String`,а у вас интовый массив.Уберите строгое сравнение.

Comment: Как тогда изменить массив? Мне нужно чтобы значения теста были строго равны нужным мне, иначе если совпадает хоть одно из них, оно пишет что правильно.

Comment: Уберите строгую проверку говорю же вам,во вторых сравнивайте значения в цикле а не за пределами.

Comment: @ilya1099 вы уж определитесь вам нужно полное совпадение массивов или что бы хотя бы один из элементов в вашем массиве и в том что приехал с постом совпадали?